# How to customize theme colors in vuetifyjs?

Tags: vuetify.js

I am trying to change the default colors to a color of my choice. But I am not able to do so. My vuetify.js file looks like this:-

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    primary: '#FF0000',
    warning: '#FFB74D'
  },
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi',
  }
});
```

If I change the color of primary to red (#FF0000) and added it to a component like this

```
<v-list color="primary"></vlist>
```

then the background color of v-list should change to red. But it's not working. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: https://codepen.io/thiagoaos/pen/KygpxV, did  you restart your app after changing that?

Comment: Yes I restarted. But the background color of v-list is still blue and not red.

Comment: try clearing your cache

Comment: I cleared my cache and also saw it in incognito mode. Still not working